# Three.js shadowCasting r88

Tags: three.js

I'm working from the most recent examples I can find, and I still can't get shadowCasting to display.

barebones jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bitsofcoad/rw48tu93/

The point light should cast a shadow from the first mesh to the second.

According to https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide:

`shadowMap.enable = true/false` is correct syntax.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer support that.

However, I get a syntax error if I use that label. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Also, https://threejs.org/docs/#api/lights/shadows/LightShadow for some more patterns

Comment: It's `renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;` Do not try to set it in the constructor.

Comment: fantastic. thanks again! updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bitsofcoad/rw48tu93/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable shadows like so:

```
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
```

And yes, if you are trying to update an outdated example, the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide) can be helpful.

Other good resources are the three.js examples, as they are consistent with the latest three.js release.

three.js r.88